Function to loop through multiple binned AQUA MODIS (NetCDF) files to create raster gridded data for chlorophyll-a in R
Issue
I downloaded binned AQUA-MODIS netcdf files (total = 3422) for daily chlorophyll-a from the Earthdata website from 2012 to 2024 for The Northern Red Sea, Egypt.
It is currently not possible to read MODIS level-3 binned (L3b) using any known package in R. RNetCDF will open the file, but does not offer any support for the complicated L3b format. ncdfCF will successfully open the file as well, but the data variables are not recognised. ncdf4, raster, terra and stars all error upon opening a L3b file.
I need to:

Extract the raw data $level-3_binned_data.BinList,
$level-3_binned_data.chlor_a, and $level-3_binned_data.BinIndex.
I want to loop through all the files, unpack the scan line data and derive the physical properties
and its locations, and finally warp the data to a latitude-longitude grid
to turn the resulting data into a CFData object (and then export to
terra for plotting or further analysis).

Question:
I don't understand how to loop through all the files to geolocate the grid cells for just the raw data. I'm a novice.
How can I do this?
My Ultimate Aim and Why I've Extracted this Data

To create a SpatRaster object using terra::rast() since chlorophyll-a will be one of the predictor variables for a species distribution model using the Maxent method from this tutorial on Github by Johan Baums, and the terra package needs raster (gridded) data. All my other predictor variables are SpatRasters and they all need to be in the same resolution, format, and extent when building the model.

Here's the manifest.txt link to get the binned AQUA MODIS netcdf files for chlorophyll-a (expires Oct 22nd 2024)
https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/requested_files_2.tar?h=ocdist410&p=/data1/d0703031e30f7f6f/requested_files

Description of L3b format
Read the files into R:
library(terra)
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
library(RNetCDF)
 
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("pvanlaake/ncdfCF")
library(ncdfCF)

#Start the file path to all the netcdf files as a variable 'folder'

folder<-"~/Documents/GIS_Data/CHL-A/"

#Make a list of all the files within the folder 

files <-list.files(folder, pattern='*.nc', full.names ="TRUE")

Loop through all the file paths and the AQUA MODIS netcdf4 files to gain access to them:
for (file in files) {
     nc=open.nc(file)
     print.nc(nc)
    }

Contents of one of the AQUA MODIS files
netcdf netcdf4 {

// global attributes:
        NC_CHAR :product_name = "AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc" ;
        NC_CHAR :title = "MODIS Level-3 Binned Data" ;
        NC_CHAR :instrument = "MODIS" ;
        NC_CHAR :platform = "Aqua" ;
        NC_CHAR :temporal_range = "day" ;
        NC_INT :start_orbit_number = 109682 ;
        NC_INT :end_orbit_number = 109698 ;
        NC_CHAR :date_created = "2024289095750000" ;
        NC_CHAR :processing_version = "unspecified" ;
        NC_CHAR :source = "satellite observations from MODIS-Aqua" ;
        NC_CHAR :history = "/sdps/sdpsoper/Science/OCSSW/DEVEL/bin/l3bin ifile=AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.nc ofile=AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc latnorth=37.0000 latsouth=5.1000 lonwest=26.7200 loneast=54.1400" ;
        NC_CHAR :time_coverage_start = "2022-12-17T00:25:01.000Z" ;
        NC_CHAR :time_coverage_end = "2022-12-18T02:59:59.000Z" ;
        NC_FLOAT :northernmost_latitude = 36.8958320617676 ;
        NC_FLOAT :southernmost_latitude = 5.10416650772095 ;
        NC_FLOAT :easternmost_longitude = 50.6941337585449 ;
        NC_FLOAT :westernmost_longitude = 26.7268047332764 ;
        NC_DOUBLE :geospatial_lat_max = 36.8958320617676 ;
        NC_DOUBLE :geospatial_lat_min = 5.10416650772095 ;
        NC_DOUBLE :geospatial_lon_max = 50.6941337585449 ;
        NC_DOUBLE :geospatial_lon_min = 26.7268047332764 ;
        NC_CHAR :geospatial_lat_units = "degrees_north" ;
        NC_CHAR :geospatial_lon_units = "degrees_east" ;
        NC_CHAR :geospatial_lat_resolution = "4.638312 km" ;
        NC_CHAR :geospatial_lon_resolution = "4.638312 km" ;
        NC_CHAR :spatialResolution = "4.638312 km" ;
        NC_INT :data_bins = 31421 ;
        NC_FLOAT :percent_data_bins = 0.132233932614326 ;
        NC_CHAR :units = "chlor_a:mg m^-3" ;
        NC_CHAR :binning_scheme = "Integerized Sinusoidal Grid" ;
        NC_CHAR :project = "Ocean Biology Processing Group (NASA/GSFC/OBPG)" ;
        NC_CHAR :institution = "NASA Goddard Space Flight Center, Ocean Ecology Laboratory, Ocean Biology Processing Group" ;
        NC_CHAR :standard_name_vocabulary = "CF Standard Name Table v36" ;
        NC_CHAR :Conventions = "CF-1.6 ACDD-1.3" ;
        NC_CHAR :naming_authority = "gov.nasa.gsfc.sci.oceandata" ;
        NC_CHAR :id = "AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc/L3/AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc" ;
        NC_CHAR :license = "https://science.nasa.gov/earth-science/earth-science-data/data-information-policy/" ;
        NC_CHAR :creator_name = "NASA/GSFC/OBPG" ;
        NC_CHAR :publisher_name = "NASA/GSFC/OBPG" ;
        NC_CHAR :creator_email = "data@oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov" ;
        NC_CHAR :publisher_email = "data@oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov" ;
        NC_CHAR :creator_url = "https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov" ;
        NC_CHAR :publisher_url = "https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov" ;
        NC_CHAR :processing_level = "L3 Binned" ;
        NC_CHAR :cdm_data_type = "point" ;
        NC_CHAR :keywords_vocabulary = "NASA Global Change Master Directory (GCMD) Science Keywords" ;
        NC_CHAR :keywords = "Earth Science > Oceans > Ocean Chemistry > Pigments > Chlorophyll; Earth Science > Oceans > Ocean Chemistry > Chlorophyll" ;

group: level-3_binned_data {
  dimensions:
    binListDim = UNLIMITED ; // (31421 currently)
    binDataDim = UNLIMITED ; // (31421 currently)
    binIndexDim = UNLIMITED ; // (4320 currently)
  types:
    compound binListType {
      NC_UINT bin_num ;
      NC_SHORT nobs ;
      NC_SHORT nscenes ;
      NC_FLOAT weights ;
      NC_FLOAT time_rec ;
    }; // binListType
    compound binDataType {
      NC_FLOAT sum ;
      NC_FLOAT sum_squared ;
    }; // binDataType
    compound binIndexType {
      NC_UINT start_num ;
      NC_UINT begin ;
      NC_UINT extent ;
      NC_UINT max ;
    }; // binIndexType
  variables:
    binListType BinList(binListDim) ;
    binDataType chlor_a(binDataDim) ;
    binIndexType BinIndex(binIndexDim) ;
  } // group level-3_binned_data

group: processing_control {

  // group attributes:
        NC_CHAR :software_name = "L3BIN" ;
        NC_CHAR :software_version = "5.14" ;
        NC_CHAR :input_sources = "AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.nc" ;
        NC_CHAR :l2_flag_names = "ATMFAIL,LAND,HILT,HISATZEN,STRAYLIGHT,CLDICE,COCCOLITH,LOWLW,CHLWARN,CHLFAIL,NAVWARN,MAXAERITER,ATMWARN,HISOLZEN,NAVFAIL,FILTER,HIGLINT" ;

  group: input_parameters {

    // group attributes:
            NC_CHAR :infile = "AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.nc" ;
            NC_CHAR :ofile = "AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc" ;
            NC_CHAR :pfile = "AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc" ;
            NC_CHAR :oformat = "netCDF4" ;
            NC_CHAR :syear = "9999" ;
            NC_CHAR :eyear = "9999" ;
            NC_CHAR :sday = "1970001" ;
            NC_CHAR :eday = "2038018" ;
            NC_CHAR :sorbit = "-1" ;
            NC_CHAR :eorbit = "-1" ;
            NC_CHAR :out_parm = ":DEFAULT:" ;
            NC_CHAR :processing_version = "unspecified" ;
            NC_CHAR :reduce_fac = "1" ;
            NC_CHAR :resolve = "" ;
            NC_CHAR :merged = "" ;
            NC_CHAR :loneast = "54.139999" ;
            NC_CHAR :lonwest = "26.719999" ;
            NC_CHAR :latnorth = "37.000000" ;
            NC_CHAR :latsouth = "5.100000" ;
            NC_CHAR :verbose = "0" ;
            NC_CHAR :unit_wgt = "0" ;
            NC_CHAR :median = "0" ;
            NC_CHAR :deflate = "5" ;
            NC_CHAR :composite_prod = "" ;
            NC_CHAR :composite_scheme = "" ;
            NC_CHAR :doi = "" ;
    } // group input_parameters
  } // group processing_control
}

#Open the netcdf files
(chl <- open_ncdf(files_Chla))

#Extract information on the variables on the netcdf file
subgroups <- chl$root$subgroups

 #OUTPUT

    #$`level-3_binned_data`
    #<Group> [131073] level-3_binned_data
    #Path      : /level-3_binned_data 

    #$processing_control
    #<Group> [131074] processing_control
    #Path      : /processing_control 
    #Subgroups : input_parameters 
    
    #Attributes:
    # id name             type    length value                                             
    # 0  software_name    NC_CHAR   6    L3BIN                                             
    # 1  software_version NC_CHAR   5    5.14                                              
    #2  input_sources    NC_CHAR  35    AQUA_MODIS.20120101.L3b.DAY.CHL.nc                
    # 3  l2_flag_names    NC_CHAR 136    
    #ATMFAIL,LAND,HILT,HISATZEN,STRAYLIGHT,CLDICE,CO...

Extract information about $binListDim
   Dims<-subgroups[["level-3_binned_data"]]$NCdims

     #OUTPUT

     $binListDim
<NCDimension>
  Inherits from: <NCObject>
  Public:
    attribute: function (att, field = "value") 
    attributes: data.frame
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
    id: 0
    initialize: function (id, name, length, unlim) 
    length: 27643
    name: binListDim
    print_attributes: function (width = 50) 
    shard: function () 
    unlim: TRUE

$binDataDim
<NCDimension>
  Inherits from: <NCObject>
  Public:
    attribute: function (att, field = "value") 
    attributes: data.frame
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
    id: 1
    initialize: function (id, name, length, unlim) 
    length: 27643
    name: binDataDim
    print_attributes: function (width = 50) 
    shard: function () 
    unlim: TRUE

$binIndexDim
<NCDimension>
  Inherits from: <NCObject>
  Public:
    attribute: function (att, field = "value") 
    attributes: data.frame
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
    id: 2
    initialize: function (id, name, length, unlim) 
    length: 4320
    name: binIndexDim
    print_attributes: function (width = 50) 
    shard: function () 
    unlim: TRUE

#Read in the variables on the netcdf4 file
   vars<-subgroups[["level-3_binned_data"]]$NCvars

   #Output

$BinList
<NCVariable>
  Inherits from: <NCObject>
  Public:
    attribute: function (att, field = "value") 
    attributes: data.frame
    CF: active binding
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
    dimids: 0
    fullname: active binding
    group: NCGroup, NCObject, R6
    id: 0
    initialize: function (id, name, group, vtype, ndims, dimids) 
    name: BinList
    ndims: 1
    netcdf4: list
    print_attributes: function (width = 50) 
    shard: function () 
    vtype: binListType
  Private:
    CFobjects: list

$chlor_a
<NCVariable>
  Inherits from: <NCObject>
  Public:
    attribute: function (att, field = "value") 
    attributes: data.frame
    CF: active binding
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
    dimids: 1
    fullname: active binding
    group: NCGroup, NCObject, R6
    id: 1
    initialize: function (id, name, group, vtype, ndims, dimids) 
    name: chlor_a
    ndims: 1
    netcdf4: list
    print_attributes: function (width = 50) 
    shard: function () 
    vtype: binDataType
  Private:
    CFobjects: list

$BinIndex
<NCVariable>
  Inherits from: <NCObject>
  Public:
    attribute: function (att, field = "value") 
    attributes: data.frame
    CF: active binding
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
    dimids: 2
    fullname: active binding
    group: NCGroup, NCObject, R6
    id: 2
    initialize: function (id, name, group, vtype, ndims, dimids) 
    name: BinIndex
    ndims: 1
    netcdf4: list
    print_attributes: function (width = 50) 
    shard: function () 
    vtype: binIndexType
  Private:
    CFobjects: list

# Reading the data
library(RNetCDF)
d <- var.get.nc(vars[[1]]$group$handle, vars[[1]]$name)
str(d)

#Output
str(d)
List of 5
 $ bin_num : num [1:27643(1d)] 12938998 12938999 12939000 12939001 12939002 ...
 $ nobs    : num [1:27643(1d)] 2 5 6 6 5 9 7 8 9 7 ...
 $ nscenes : num [1:27643(1d)] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ weights : num [1:27643(1d)] 1.41 2.24 2.45 2.45 2.24 ...
 $ time_rec: num [1:27643(1d)] 1.2e+09 3.0e+09 3.6e+09 3.6e+09 3.0e+09 ...

I'm not sure if I've mapped the scan lines here and I feel very confused
Map the scan lines into a grid to create gridded raster data
grp <- grp.inq.nc(nc_Chl, "/level-3_binned_data")$self
chlor_a<-var.get.nc(grp, "chlor_a")
binlist<-var.get.nc(grp, "BinList") 
bin_index<-var.get.nc(grp, "BinIndex")


Its not clear to me here where you are stuck. What does your code do, and why doesn't it do what you want to do with it? Can you show some maps maybe? Usually the answer to "how do I do X on multiple files" is first to write a function that does X on one file and then to loop over them.

Is your problem essentially starting with trying to get the lat-long and data values from one of the files? And here you've tried three different NetCDF-reading packages?

It is currently not possible to read MODIS level-3 binned (L3b) using any known package in R. RNetCDF will open the file, but does not offer any support for the complicated L3b format. ncdfCF will successfully open the file as well, but the data variables are not recognised. ncdf4, raster, terra and stars all error upon opening a L3b file.

Have you got a link to a description of the L3b format?

I want to unpack the scan line data and derive the physical property and its location and then warp the data to a latitude-longitude grid to turn the resulting data into a CFData object (and then export to terra for plotting or further analysis).

Hey Spacedman. I just put a link to the description of the L3b file format in the question and I've made it clearer what I want to do

Answered here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79104406/creating-a-spatraster-with-multiple-binned-aqua-modis-netcdf-files-with-the-fu - its nice to know when thing are cross-posted, I've been trying to work out the sinusoidal grid layout...

Hey Spaceman. At the point when I wrote this question, we had not figured out how to extract the data from the binned files and this specific question was about geolocating the opened files to created gridded data. The Stackoverflow question was about how to extract the data from the files. After a lot of effort, Patrick worked it all out and posted it in Stackoverflow.

The question on Stackoverflow was edited so many times as the question kept expanding and changing and I also change the title 3 times. I do apologise
